# Speed up openpyxl reading

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working on a quite large program that is taking data from again, quite a large excel spreadsheet. 
For some strange reason it takes though ages to load this big excel file, and I was hoping to speed it up somehow. 
I did my own research and tried read_only, but that didnt allow me to read any cells (at least the way shown below). Any suggestions would be highly welcome.

```
def LoadSheet(Filename,worksheet_nr):
    import time as t
    st = t.clock()
    wb = xl.load_workbook(str(Filename))#workbook, loading workbook
    Sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()#Worksheets, shows all sheets in the workbook loaded
    ActiveSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(Sheets[worksheet_nr])#Selects the first sheet
    print round(t.clock() - st,3), "seconds of loading time."
    print "Sheet is loaded and reading..."
    return ActiveSheet



def CountRC_nr(ActiveSheet, StartR,StartC):
    R = StartR#Selected starting Row number
    C = StartC#Selected starting Column number
    Val = None #Value in cell (Right now, none is selected, thus zero value)
    while (Val != "None"):
        Val = str(ActiveSheet.cell(row=R,column=C).value)
        R += 1

    NumberRows = R - StartR - 1
    Val = None
    R=StartR

    while (Val != "None"):
        Val = str(ActiveSheet.cell(row=R,column=C).value)
        C += 1
    NumberColumns = C - StartC - 1

    return NumberRows, NumberColumns
```

Since some of you requested to see how I used read_only, here the modified code:

```
def LoadSheet(Filename,worksheet_nr):
    import time as t
    st = t.clock()
    wb = xl.load_workbook(str(Filename), read_only = True)#workbook, loading workbook
    Sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()#Worksheets, shows all sheets in the workbook loaded
    ActiveSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(Sheets[worksheet_nr])#Selects the first sheet
    print round(t.clock() - st,3), "seconds of loading time."
    print "Sheet is loaded and reading..."
    return ActiveSheet



def CountRC_nr(ActiveSheet, StartR,StartC):
    R = StartR#Selected starting Row number
    C = StartC#Selected starting Column number
    Val = None #Value in cell (Right now, none is selected, thus zero value)
    while (Val != "None"):
        Val = str(ActiveSheet.cell(row=R,column=C).value)
        R += 1

    NumberRows = R - StartR - 1
    Val = None
    R=StartR

    while (Val != "None"):
        Val = str(ActiveSheet.cell(row=R,column=C).value)
        C += 1
    NumberColumns = C - StartC - 1

    return NumberRows, NumberColumns
```

Comment: It would be better to focus on the problems with read-only mode. Your code also seems to be working against the openpyxl API.

Comment: Charlie, sorry, I didnt get what you mean. What do you mean its against openpyxl API? Everything works correctly and all I wished was to speed it up, but any ways Im trying aint working. If you know better on how to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide some actual sample code using read-only mode (don't use `ws.cell()` here).

Comment: Charlie Clark, how else do I get the cell value if not through ws.cell? Or more specifically to my code, ActiveSheet.cell(R,C).value...?

Comment: Use just iterate through the rows. Using `ws.cell` in read-only mode will force openpyxl to start parsing the file again and again which is very slow. And if you have very large files read-only is the way to go. You might also want to look at xlrd which is slightly faster.

Comment: Charlie Clark, can you please show how to do exactly that what you just mentioned? Or give a reference? Cause that seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to do: you have two unconnected functions.

Comment: In the code I first run the first function, then the second one... the first one loads the sheet for me so that I can access the data, the second one allows me, now with the sheet stored in memory, to  count its size. (built in functions did give me correct numbers.)

Comment: What do you want to get from the worksheets? At the moment it looks like you just want to find out how big the worksheet is. Please do not use `str()` the way you do (particularly when checking for `None`).

Comment: The excel sheet contains lots of numbers... all i need to do is read the data from it, which I later transfer into a big numpy array, which allows me to manage it to the required needs. The counting function just counts how big the data of interest is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've already said, you're working against the API. If the dimension of the worksheet are known then you can access them otherwise you can build your own counters there is little point.

Read-only mode is very fast for individual lookups, but as **each** lookup involves parsing all cells in the rows up to the one of interest it is very inefficient for lots of them, such as your code is using.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
for ws in wb:
    print(ws.dimensions)
    for row in ws.rows:
         for cell in row:
             print(cell.value)  # do whatever you want with the cell
```

You can easily convert rows into NumPy arrays using `(cell.value for cell in row)` but the Pandas library will also read worksheets directly into data frames.